# How many Kafka consumer needed if they're slow?

Tags: apache-kafka

scenario:
10 Kafka messages per sec
2 partitions
to process one message consumer needs 2 sec

My initial answer: 20 consumers since they're slow. 5 groups, each group 4 consumers.

Comment: 10 messages/second. It takes 2 seconds for a consumer to process a message, you need 5 consumers to keep up. Start there, if it cannot keep up add more consumers.

Comment: Oh and you only need one group for your five consumers. Members of a group consumer in parallel. If you have multiple groups each group is going to consume the same objects.

Comment: Hi @bhspencer, why only one group for your five consumers? Would it be too slow?

Comment: In Kafka a consumer group is how you process messages in parallel. Each member of the group will be given a different message to process, in sum the group will process all of the messages. If you have two groups each group will process all the messages and so each message will get processed twice.

Comment: Hi @bhspencer, This sounds reasonable. But you didn't consider the time factor in this question all the time? Is it not necessary?

Comment: My mistake I am sorry you are correct. To process 10 per second you need 20 consumers. But you only want 1 consumer group.